# Appium - iOS - App paths need to be absolute or an URL to a compressed file

Tags: ios, appium

Trying to connect to Appium Automatic Server with my capabilities results in `An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: Chrome. App paths need to be absolute or an URL to a compressed file`

These are the capabilities I am trying:

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "12.1",
  "app": "Chrome",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 6"
}
```

Do you know how I can find the absolute path to Chrome?

I am using Appium 1.12.1 and Xcode 10.2

Comment: Are you trying to automate native app or web app? if you are trying to automate native app, you must provide **ipa file** or url where your file is. If the app is already install in device, you can use bundleId instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing some concepts here regarding the capabilities.

Appium is an automation framework that allows you to automate native apps, provided that you actually own them. Automation on iOS requires that the apps are signed with a developer key, it is not possible to automate a production application and much less an Apple Store one.

Appium can automate the following types of apps ([Desired Capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)):

- Native apps (ipa files), signed with a developer certificate. Distribution certificates do not work!
- Simulator apps (app.zip files). This will only work in iOS Simulator, since they're compiled for x86 instruction set and not ARM.
- TestFlight and alike (HockeyApp, etc) apps. In that case, you don't set an `app` capability but set a `bundleId` one. You have to manually install the app through the platform, then start it with Appium using the bundle ID.

Again, automation ONLY works if the application is signed with a developer certificate. Applications released in the market are always signed with Distribution certificates that disallow the use of this framework.

So, you cannot "automate Chrome". What you can do, is automate Safari browser with Appium, check [Appium - iOS Mobile Web Automation](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/#ios-mobile-web-automation). This only works with Safari. It will make Appium behave more or less like a Selenium driver, but using an iPhone instead.

Comment: I see... thank you for this info!  I will pursue using Safari

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS COMPLETELY WRONG. I can automate with Appium any application which is already installed on my phone (installed from the App Store with distribution certificate). What you mean is INSTALLING your own app on the phone requires a disitribution or Ad-Hoc certificate. But automating (inspecting elements and tapping and typing text) is possible with any application. You just pass the bundleId in the desired capabilities and XCuiTest does the rest.